# React Native InAppBrowser Cognito Auth Issue

Tags: android, react-native, authentication, aws-amplify

Currently trying to find a fix to an annoying 'feature' with following packages

```
"react": "17.0.2",
"react-native": "0.65.1",
"react-native-inappbrowser-reborn": "3.6.3",
"@react-navigation/drawer": "6.1.4",
"@react-navigation/native": "6.0.2",
"@react-navigation/native-stack": "6.1.0",
"react-native-screens": "3.6.0",
"aws-amplify": "4.2.10",
```

App presents user with a button to log into google and uses Amplify Auth configured for urlOpener in auth options as follows

```
    urlOpener: async (url, redirectSignIn) => {
      try {
        await InAppBrowser.isAvailable();
        console.log(`urlOpener: calling url: ${url}, redirectsignIn: ${redirectSignIn}`)
        InAppBrowser.openAuth(url, redirectSignIn, {
          dismissButtonStyle: 'cancel',
          showTitle: false,
          enableUrlBarHiding: true,
          enableDefaultShare: false,
          ephemeralWebSession: false,
          forceCloseOnRedirection: true
        }).then((response) => {
          console.log('urlOpener: response: ', JSON.stringify(response));
          if (response.type === 'cancel') {
            console.log('urlOpener: cancel:');
            AuthStore.setIsFedratedSignIn(false);
          } else if (response.type === 'success' && response.url) {
            console.log('urlOpener: success: url: ', response.url);
            Linking.openURL(response.url);
          }
        })
      } catch (err) {
        console.log('urlOpener: error: ', JSON.stringify(err));
      }
    },
```

Cognito is all fine and we can use hosted UI to prove the login process with Google is working and correct redirect url is returned

User authenticates and the auth page sits there and goes nowhere. Essentially it looks like the auth process never finishes and no redirect is returned or passed back to app.

User closes the auth process and returns to app
User clicks google again and the auth process completes without any delay or login required and the redirect is returned and the user is logged in and we see the appropriate logging occuring.

The only difference between 1st and 2nd attempt is something we spotted in the android logs.

ONLY on the second attempt do we see the following

`I ActivityTaskManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.VIEW cat=[android.intent.category.BROWSABLE] dat=cortexmonitorapp://signin?code=b3bbf90f-5b8c-4b94-97c0-a2a9bcaedbc1&state=hF8xky8sYKMaTSA06j1X2IsKhaqDtJ7r flg=0x14000000 cmp=com.cortexmonitoring/.MainActivity (has extras)} from uid 10116`

Trying to workout why it only comes thru on the second attempt, essentially when the user is already logged in from the 1st attempt

Is it cognito not returning the redirect? We doubt that. Its been tested and tested and always returns
Is it InAppBrowser not sensing it? passing it on?
We know the linking in the app is fine since when Android does pass on the intent to the app we see it actioned in the app so as far as we can tell the schemes are correct and the linking is working.

For some reason that 1st attempt never generates the intent.

Anyone seen this before and resolved???
Anyone got alternative methods or packages that work consistently???

Thanks in advance
Utterly stuck right now

Answer (score 2):

So this issue was only really apparent on Android Sim. On a physical device it seemed OK

After some testing I can only really put it down to the state of Chrome when the phone is essentially factory default.

Chrome asks some questions re sync and T&C's before opening the auth tabs. And auth fails.

If Chrome has been used and the questions answered then the auth works which is why the second attempt always seemed to work